# Why I can't use should_receive and assigns in one controller spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I tried add `assigns` to my `update` action spec in controller

```
it "update the content" do
  Answer.should_receive(:find).with(answer.id.to_s).and_return(answer)
  answer.should_receive(:update_attributes).with("content" => "Changed content")

  put :update, id: answer.id, app_id: app.id, answer: {content: "Changed content"}

  assigns(:answer).content.should eq('Changed content') # explicitly permitted
  response.status.should eq 406
end
```

but I get error:

```
 Failure/Error: assigns(:answer).content.should eq('Changed content') # explicitly permitted

   expected: "Changed content"
        got: "base content"

   (compared using ==)
```

but when I comment:

`#answer.should_receive(:update_attributes).with("content" => "Changed content")`

spec pass. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty logical.

When you do:

```
answer.should_receive(:update_attributes).with("content" => "Changed content")
```

`update_attributes` is not fired.

You could use `and_call_original` to have the method fired. [See doc](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations).

Comment: But after that the OP is calling `put :update` shouldn't that change the content (assuming the update is correctly implemented)?